# React useCallback/useEffect deps object property usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Is it correct to include in useEffect/useCallback deps only used props, but not whole object?

For example:

```
function Component (props) {
  useEffect(() => console.log(props.someValue), [props.someValue]) // ? eslint plugin tells that you should include props, not props.someValue.
  return someVal
}
```

Comment: Yup this is a valid code.

Comment: ``function Component (props) {
  const { someValue } = props;
  useEffect(() => console.log(someValue), [someValue])
}``

Is this better/different? I also don't quite get the eslint behavior. Or this code just blocking eslint to do its job correctly?

Comment: Can you provide a exact eslint plugin message?

Comment: @zmag My case was:
`const formik = useFormik();const someCustomChange = useCallback(() => {
     // some code here using only formik.setValues, nothing else from formik
}, [formik.setValues])`
And eslint tells  `eslint: React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'formik'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. [react-hooks/exhaustive-deps]`

I dont want to use destructuring because of code style, i am using a lot stuff from formik object(`formik` kind of namespace for readability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FYI: `props` is an object that is passed to component and whatever props you pass it is going to be a property of that object.

If you want to run `callback` when `props.someValue` has changed then you should only provide `props.someValue` in deps array. Your code  will work also with `props` but there `[READ BELOW]`.

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/beautiful-torvalds-js6jny?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A4%2C1-53%2C1)

> Use `props.someValue` as dependency instead of `props`

But problem comes when parent component renders without changing `someValue` let say there is one more state `someValue2` then if that changes then adding `props` as deps will trigger callback function of `useEffect`

As you can see in the following example that `props.someValue has changed with props.someValue` will only log in console if `props.someValue` gets changed not when `props` gets changed

```
function Component(props) {
  // ? eslint plugin tells that you should include props, not props.someValue.
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("props.someValue has changed with props.someValue");
  }, [props.someValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("props.someValue has changed with props");
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "bisque",
        padding: "1rem",
      }}
    >
      <h1>In Component</h1>
      <h1>{props.someValue}</h1>
      <h1>{props.someValue2}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [someValue, setSomeValue1] = useState(0);
  const [someValue2, setSomeValue2] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "lightcoral",
          padding: "1rem",
        }}
      >
        <h1>In Component</h1>

        <h1>someValue 1: {someValue}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => setSomeValue1((c) => c + 1)}> + </button>
        <button onClick={() => setSomeValue1((c) => c - 1)}> - </button>

        <h1>someValue 2: {someValue2}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => setSomeValue2((c) => c + 1)}> + </button>
        <button onClick={() => setSomeValue2((c) => c - 1)}> - </button>
      </div>
      <Component someValue={someValue} someValue2={someValue2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```